# (drag n) drop files in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

Because a demo is worth 72.814 words: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/J575b/3/show/

That's the simplest demo. Three events: drag over, drag leave and drop. `over` and `leave` work as expected (the class is added and removed). The drop however doesn't!

Like IE, it opens the dropped file in the window. In Chrome the event cancels and the dragging file is dropped (and ignored in this case).

The drop event doesn't even trigger in Firefox!?

What's going on? I thought this worked... (It does in Chrome. It doesn't in Opera 11.64.)

**EDIT**

**Fixed**, thanks to Adriano: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/J575b/5/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ondragover` handler to this:

```
drop.ondragover = function() {
    this.classList.add('over');
    return false;
};
```

Note the `return false` line, from [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#droptargets) you need to `preventDefault()` or return a false value from the function to allow the drop.

Comment: Wow. That was so simple. I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop but not the one you suggested. Stupid Google ;)

Comment: Thanks, it made me mad this noon too :). ondrop was not even fired until I replaced ondragenter with ondragover. What is difference between these events on FF? Both them work well on Chrome.

Comment: @Tiendq drag & drop needs "confirmation" that the object you're dragging (and it'll be dropped) can be handled. Well API isn't the best you can see in a specification (take a look to [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html), little bit old but it "explains" the problem).